# Map a nested array in Ruby but it's return all item is nil

Tags: ruby

I have a simple code recursive map an array with hashs and nested array.I want to get each item change to new values for method return value, like map always do. 
But I getting a nil array return, I don't know why?

> [nil, nil, nil, nil, [nil]]

```
class DataTest
  def m_arr
    [
      {:path => 'index'},
      {:path => 'about'},
      {:path =>'galleries'},
      {:path =>'views'},
      {:path =>'contact',
       :child => [
         {:path => 'contact/find_us'}
       ]}
    ]
  end

  def menu_struct_arr( m_arr )
    m_arr.map do |menu|
      menu = menulize(menu)
      if menu.child
        menu_struct_arr(menu.child)
      end
    end
  end

  Menu = Struct.new( :path, :child )

  def menulize(item)
    Menu.new( item[:path], item[:child] ) 
  end
end
```

I think is the last command:(if menu.child), getting nil and return to each item when mapping. Please correct me, if I guess wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add returning value to `map` method. In your case with recursive function or even if `if` statement wasn't triggered it always be nil. So you should fix your method with this one:

```
def menu_struct_arr( m_arr )
  m_arr.map do |menu|
    menu = menulize(menu)
    if menu.child
      menu_struct_arr(menu.child)
    end
    menu
  end
end
```

I'd recommend you to write that with some clenup.

```
class DataTest
  Menu = Struct.new(:path, :childs)

  ARR = 
    [
      {path: 'index'},
      {path: 'about'},
      {path: 'galleries'},
      {path: 'views'},
      {path: 'contact', childs: [{path: 'contact/find_us'}]}
    ]

  def array_menulize(items)
    items.map do |item|
      single_menulize(item)
    end
  end

  def single_menulize(item)
    menulized = Menu.new(item[:path], item[:childs])
    array_menulize(menulized.childs) if menulized.childs
    menulized
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it's get a Struct array return, but how could I iterate the hash inside child? Or I shouldn't use this data structure, or I should try other way to loop the Menu trees?

Comment: Actually, I cannot understand why you tried with your approach and for what. But I made some clarification for you about error. So if you want just iterate through `Hash` in ruby it's as simple as with `Array`. Use methods like [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-each).